# Escape CoD:BO's main menu in the PC version

Tags: pc, call-of-duty-black-ops

I've been trying to escape the main menu in Call of Duty: Black Ops, but I can't find out how. All the guides I find out there just say: "Alternately press the right and left trigger". None of them seem to have tried it for the PC version.

A few of them suggest: "Left and right mouse buttons will probably work on the PC". Well, I've been trying it like hell, my mouse almost bust open, and I still haven't managed to do it.

I've already finished the campaign. Am I missing something?

Comment: This question, and answer, sound very strange to me.

Comment: Have you played the game? If not, it would be pretty strange indeed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just look down at your legs and press the space bar.

Comment: No problem. For what it's worth, I went through the same confusion until I figured it out :)